# PHP laravel 4.2 API Routing URL with postman

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel4.2 trying to create a RESTFUL API, but getting error when I'm trying to hit URL`{localhost/TPM/public/api/books}` in postman.

what would be the URL for this??

Controller:

[image]

Router:

[image]

Comment: You need to attach more information here. There isn't enough to go on. The only thing I can think of is that you should never have to type in the local path to your script in postman, up to the `public` bit. Have you tried just going to `api/books`?

Comment: yuup. I tried with localhost/api/books  and localhost/TPM/public/api/books. but bad luck again... here TPM is my app name

Comment: How about the port? Are you serving this with `php artisan serve`, or running it in vagrant? By default it doesn't serve on port 80.

Comment: I'm using xampp in local.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/books when I hit this in postman it is continuously loading without result.....

Answer (score 0):

Try with `return Response::json(['result' => true]);` in your `index` method.

In addition, you can check the logs file for clues of what's going on in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

I think in Laravel 4.2 you needed to perform a `composer dump-autoload` if created new classes but not sure.

Comment: I tried with your return statement and url is http://localhost/TPM/api/books. No luck it is saying "no object found".

Comment: php artisan route command is working n displaying all the routes list.